# How to see total Commander kills in Battlefield 4?

Tags: battlefield-4, battlelog

I play a good bit of commander mode in Battlefield 4. There are a few ways to get kills as a commander (destroying an enemy gunship, dropping a supply crate on someone), but most notably is launching a cruise missile. I recently get 10 kills in a match with missiles, but looking all throughout Battlelog, I can't find any recording of total commander or total cruise missile kills.

Is this stat available at all, either through Battlelog or through the Battlelog API?

Comment: The commander-mode tag is entirely unneccessary.  Battlefield 4 covers all of the game, and we don't have nearly enough questions to require additional tags for filtering.

Comment: Commander mode did exist in other battlefield games. Thats why i added it

Comment: You don't need a tag for it though, it's still just a feature of the game.

Answer (score 4):

As of right now, **no.**

Kills from the commander mode do not get logged under a weapon or vehicle stat: [image]

But you can view up to 30 kills with the cruise missile in the Offensive Commander Assignment:
[image]

Comment: Yeah, I know. But I only just now unlocked that, and I've definitely already gotten 20+, probably closer to 40+ kills. I'm curious to know how many

Comment: @SSumner unfortunately, that is the only place as of right now that logs it. Hopefully an update soon will fix that! :)

Answer (score -3):

You can see every 100 kills because you get a service star each time you reach 100 kills

Comment: Nope, that's not true. You earn commander service stars the same way you earn class service stars - with points, not kills. Plus, I have 13 commander service stars, in about 19 hours. There's no way I was getting 1 kill/minute consistently in commander mode.